# how to check that a parameter in params exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

how to check that the parameters are not empty?

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email)
```

I tried

```
if params.require(:recovery_password).permit(:email).blank?
```

But got the following error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: recovery_password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will work for you.

```
if params[:user][:email].blank?
  .....
end
```

Keep coding and learning